# Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules in React, GSAP

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, gsap

I am trying to use GSAP with react to create an image reveal animation. Here is my code

```
  import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
  import './JumboRight.scss'
  import CSSRulePlugin from "gsap/CSSRulePlugin";
  import { gsap, TimelineLite, Power2 } from "gsap";
  import student from "../../assets/student.webp";
  import {connect} from 'react-redux';
  const JumboRight = (props) =>{

    gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin);
    let containerRef = useRef(null);
  
    let heroRef = useRef(null);
    let imageReveal = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".hero:after")

    const tl = new TimelineLite()
    useEffect(()=> {
      tl.to(containerRef, 0, {
      visibility: "visible"
      }).to(imageReveal, 1.4, {width: "0%", ease: Power2.easeInOut})
    })
    //remaining code
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet]

What could be the reason? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing it's being blocked for security reasons? Try hosting it on a live server and see if it works there.

Comment: In general we don't recommend using the CSSRulePlugin though. We recommend animating an actual element or animating a CSS variable instead. More info about that in the CSSRulePlugin docs. Also we recommend the more condensed [GSAP 3 formatting](https://greensock.com/3-migration/).